# AnyLogic parameter variation output to Excel efficiency

Tags: excel, anylogic

My model is running a parameter variation experiment for an external optimization problem. I have to export the output of each experiment replication to Excel. I was using a function that is triggered at `On destroy:` in the main agent and then using the following code for each output value:

`ExcelResults.setCellValue(planned_leadtime_1, varExcelSheetName, ActRow, ActColumn++);`

Currently, there are around 90 output values for each replication. Unfortunately, this method makes runtime very slow.

Trying to solve the issue, I stored the results of each replication in an ArrayList within the parameter variation experiment in `After simulation run:`. Now I would like to transfer this ArrayList directly to Excel in `After iteration:` and reset the ArrayList.

Is it possible to transfer the ArrayList directly to Excel without iterating over every value in the list by using `setCellValue()`? Or is there another computationally efficient way to transfer the output of the parameter variation experiment to Excel?

Comment: write to csv, much faster. See help and example models to see how

Comment: I now transfer the ArrayList directly to CSV which works well. Thanks

Comment: feel free to share the full solution here as well (as an answer). Helps future people with similar issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue I stored the value of each replication in an ArrayList `experimentsResults` in the parameter variation experiment. After each iteration, the ArrayList representing an iteration of multiple replications is transferred to a CSV file.

To store the data in an ArrayList a java class was created to represent all the data that needs to be transferred to the list. Then the code below is used in a function that is being triggered in `After simulation run:`

```
ReplicationData row = new ReplicationData();
    row.experimentDescription = experimentDescription;
    row.varCurrentIteration = varCurrentIteration;
experimentResults.add(row);
```

To write the ArrayList to CSV I used this function that is triggered in `After iteration:`

```
for(int j=0; j<experimentResults.size(); j++)
{

    String resultstring=""; 
    
    resultstring = experimentResults.get(j).experimentDescription+";"+
        experimentResults.get(j).varCurrentIteration+";"+       
    csvResults.println(resultstring);
}
csvResults.close();
```

The main thing that I was not aware of, was to place the Text File from the connectivity pallet directly in the experiment. This improved the writing speed a lot. After the experiment, the CSV file can be easily converted to Excel.